# How was Leonardo of Pisa's book liber abbaci distributed?

Tags: biographical-details, number-theory

In 1202 Leonardo of Pisa, later known as Fibonacci, wrote, in his book "liber abbaci", his explanation of a means of expressing numbers, and manipulating them, that gave us arithmetic as we know it today. My question is: how was that book distributed, since the printing press did not arrive in Europe for another two hundred years? How many copies were produced?

Comment: Before pintinp press, books were "reproduced" by [amanuensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanuensis).

Comment: For manuscripts, see Baldassarre Boncompagni, [Della vita e delle opere di Leonardo Pisano](https://books.google.it/books?id=FoyNx40Ih0gC) (1852) and B.Boncompagni, [Intorno ad alcune opere di Leonardo Pisano](https://books.google.it/books?id=MXUwskni5gwC) (1854).

Comment: There was only one method of distribution of books before printing: copying them by hand. This answers your question "how". On your other question: how many copies were distributed, before the printing press arrived, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Interesting question, impossible to answer. I'd be interested to know too... :-(

Comment: @vonbrand - not impossible... The extant manuscripts are listed in the above books: unfortunately, they are in Italian.

Comment: It seems to me a more general question is interesting:  How would Leonardo have done this?  Hired some local professional copiers to copy the book for him?  Or maybe he was a man of leisure, had many servants, and assigned one or more of them to make his copies?

Answer (score 1):

Some English Sources for [Leonardo Piasno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci) :

- Laurence Sigler (editor), [Fibonacci’s Liber Abaci](https://books.google.it/books?id=PilhoGJeKBUC&pg=PR4) (2002): unfortunately, the *Introduction* does not give details on the manuscripts. Only :

> *Liber abbaci*, or the Book of Calculation, appeared first in 1202, and then
>   again in a second version in 1228. [...] This English translation is prepared from Baldassarre Boncompagni's [Latin edition of 1857](http://lhldigital.lindahall.org/cdm/compoundobject/collection/math/id/8734/rec/1).

- Barnabas Hughes (editor), [Fibonacci's De Practica Geometrie](https://books.google.it/books?id=aEOZThAbCKIC&pg=PR11) (2008): good introduction.
- Jens Høyrup, [Jacopo da Firenze's Tractatus Algorismi and Early Italian Abbacus Culture](https://books.google.it/books?id=XZhPC1Y-SOUC&printsec=frontcover) (2007): **Fibonacci and the Abbaco**, page 41-44.